# Magento 2 [2.2.6] not reaching the success page

Tags: magento2

We seem to have an adhoc issue where after successfully receiving the payment via paypal it tries to go back to this URL:

https://xxxyyy.com/paypal/hostedpro/return/?PayerID=

However more often than not it will not make its way to the success page - just hangs on a blank page with this URL.

All the emails get sent and the status on the shop is all perfect.

I have looked around and seen posts simlar even on Adobe support but no answers.

Let me know if I need to share anything else to help with this issue.